Error utf-8 con psycopg2, con postgres, pgadmin, python, no encuentro explicacion
Estoy corriendo un codigo en python, con una interfaz echa en tkinter, tengo el mismo problema en otro codigo similar. Basicamente cuando iniciamos el codigo con "Run without debugging", y hacemos click en el boton de de display, o cualquier boton que interactue con la base de datos, vemos el error en pantalla.
Incluire el codigo y el error, junto con las especificaciones de mi sistema. Mi compoañero prueba el codigo en su computadora de escritorio, y si funciona.
Error:

Codigo:
'''This function displays all the contact records from the database'''
def DisplayRecords(self):
    self.ClearScreen()
    # Defining two scrollbars
    scroll_x = ttk.Scrollbar(self.frame_1, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    scroll_y = ttk.Scrollbar(self.frame_1, orient=VERTICAL)
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.frame_1, columns=self.columns, height=400, selectmode="extended", yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set, xscrollcommand=scroll_x.set)
    scroll_y.config(command=self.tree.yview)
    scroll_y.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
    scroll_x.config(command=self.tree.xview)
    scroll_x.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

    # Table headings
    for col in self.columns:
        self.tree.heading(col, text=col.replace('ID', 'ID ').replace('FechaVencimiento', 'Fecha de Vencimiento').replace('NombreGenerico', 'Nombre Genérico').replace('NombreComercial', 'Nombre Comercial'), anchor=W)
        self.tree.column(col, width=150, anchor=W)

    self.tree.pack()
    self.tree.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.Selected)


    # ------ CAMBIOS -------
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(dbname="farmacia", 
                                      user="", 
                                      password="", 
                                      host="", 
                                      port="")
        curs = connection.cursor()
        curs.execute("""SELECT * FROM Public."Medicamento" """)
        rows=curs.fetchall()
        if not rows:
            messagebox.showinfo("Database Empty","There is no data to show",parent=self.window)
            connection.close()
            self.ClearScreen()
        else:
            connection.close()
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Error!",f"Error due to {str(e)}",parent=self.window)
    # ---- CAMBIOS -----
    # Inserting row values
    for list in rows:
        self.tree.insert("", 'end', text=(rows.index(list)+1), values=(list[0], list[1], list[2], list[3], list[4]))

Especificaciones:

Nombre del SO    Microsoft Windows 11 Home Single Language
Versión  10.0.22631 compilación 22631 Descripción adicional del SO   No
disponible Fabricante del SO Microsoft Corporation Nombre del
sistema  LAPTOP-JHVE7OV1 Fabricante del sistema  LENOVO Modelo del
sistema  82AU Tipo de sistema    PC basado en x64 SKU del
sistema  LENOVO_MT_82AU_BU_idea_FM_Legion 5 15IMH05
Procesador   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10300H CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2496 Mhz, 4
procesadores principales, 8 procesadores lógicos Versión y fecha de
BIOS LENOVO EFCN54WW, 14/2/2022 Versión de SMBIOS    3.2 Versión de
controladora integrada   1.54 Modo de BIOS   UEFI Fabricante de la placa
base LENOVO Producto de placa base   LNVNB161216 Versión de la placa
base SDK0J40679 WIN Rol de plataforma    Móvil Estado de arranque
seguro   Desactivada Configuración de PCR7   Se necesita elevación de
privilegios para ver Directorio de Windows   C:\WINDOWS Directorio del
sistema  C:\WINDOWS\system32 Dispositivo de
arranque \Device\HarddiskVolume4 Configuración regional  España Capa
de abstracción de hardware   Versión = "10.0.22621.2506" Nombre de
usuario   Zona horaria   Hora estándar de Argentina Memoria física
instalada (RAM)  8,00 GB Memoria física total    7,87 GB Memoria física
disponible   1,39 GB Memoria virtual total   16,4 GB Memoria virtual
disponible   7,88 GB Espacio de archivo de paginación    8,50 GB Archivo
de paginación    D:\pagefile.sys Protección de DMA de kernel Activada
Seguridad basada en virtualización   No habilitado Directiva de Control
de aplicaciones de Windows Defender  Impuesta Directiva de modo
usuario de Control de aplicaciones de Windows Defender   Desactivada
Compatibilidad con cifrado de dispositivo    Se necesita elevación de
privilegios para ver Hyper-V - Extensiones de modo de monitor VM Sí
Hyper-V - Extensiones de traducción de dirección de segundo nivel    Sí
Hyper-V - Virtualización habilitada en Firmware  Sí Hyper-V
-Protección de ejecución de datos    Sí

Tengo python, pgadmin, postgres y vscode actualizados. La config del sistema, esta en utf-8, incluido el codigo de python en vscode, la base de datos tambien esta en utf-8.
No he podido encontrar casi nada aparte de esto:
Error en mi conexión de Postgresql con python: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte
Cualquier ayuda la agradezco de antemano.

Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Cuándo ocurren errores, usualmente se imprime la traza de la pila (stack trace), esto es por una buena razón y es buena idea que incluyas esta información en tu pregunta, pues ayuda a ver dónde se origina el problema. Un saludo.
